# ORDER BY with DELETE not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have written this delete query to remove the duplicate entries from table but when I run this query it will keep the old rows and delete the newest one. I want to keep the newest inserted rows and want to delete the old ones. I have appended `ORDER BY` clause in delete query but it's not working.

```
DELETE t2
FROM   user_deprovision t1
JOIN   user_deprovision t2 ON (
    t2.UserName  = t1.UserName  AND
    t2.GroupName = t1.Groupname AND
    t2.id > t1.id)
ORDER BY t1.DeletedDate;
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: remove `t2`.its misplaced.

Comment: Why would you want to order a delete? Makes no sense.

Comment: @tomalak: I want to keep data with latest data only for that I tried ORDER BY if it works

Comment: Do you have a date or timestamp column?  Try not to use the primary key for any business purpose.  Before you work on a DELETE, can you write a SELECT that returns the rows you want to delete?

Comment: @Eric yes I have a datetime column in this table

Answer (score 0):

Let's write a query that returns the latest time for a user name and group name.

```
SELECT
    UserName, GroupName, MAX(deprovision_time)
FROM
    user_deprovision
GROUP BY
    UserName, GroupName
```

Now, let's adapt this to your purpose.  In Oracle, I might do something to turn that into a temporary table, but I'll use correlated subqueries here instead.

```
DELETE FROM user_deprovision AS dp1
WHERE dp1.deprovision_time <
    ANY (SELECT deprovision_time FROM user_deprovision AS dp2
         WHERE dp1.UserName  = dp2.UserName
         AND   dp1.GroupName = dp2.GroupName);
```

We can turn this into a join instead.

```
SELECT dp1.id
FROM   user_deprovision AS dp1
JOIN   user_deprovision AS dp2
ON     dp1.UserName  = dp2.UserName
AND    dp1.GroupName = dp2.GroupName
WHERE
       dp1.deprovision_time < dp2.deprovision_time
```

And the corresponding delete is:

```
DELETE FROM user_deprovision
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT dp1.id
    FROM   user_deprovision AS dp1
    JOIN   user_deprovision AS dp2
    ON     dp1.UserName  = dp2.UserName
    AND    dp1.GroupName = dp2.GroupName
    WHERE
           dp1.deprovision_time < dp2.deprovision_time);
```